# Im trying to test uplading a library to pypi i just made a verry simple one

Tags: setuptools, pypi, twine

How the folders and files are structured:
[image: Immage]

all the text in `README.txt`

```
This is a verry simple calculator.
```

all the text in `CHANGELOG.txt`

```
Change Log
==========

0.0.1 (19/10/2020)
-------------------
- First Release
```

all the text in `LICENCE.txt` (edited out my name with ------- ------)

```
Copyright 2020 ------- -----

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

all the text in `MANIFEST.in`

```
global-include *.txt *.py
```

all the text in `__init__.py`

```
def add_num(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract_num(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multiply_num(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def divide_num(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

def exponent_num(num1, num2):
    return num1 ** num2
```

all the test in `setup.py` (edited out my email and name)

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

classifiers = [
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Intended Audience :: Education',
    'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
]

setup(
    name='martinsimplecalculator',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='a basic calculator',
    long_description_content_type='txt',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read() + '\n\n' + open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(),
    url='',
    author='----',
    author_email='----',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=classifiers,
    keywords='calculator',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['']

)
```

the rest of the files were made with the command:

```
python3 setup.py sdist
```

and after i typed in:

```
twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

and typed in my username and password i got this error:

```
HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
The description failed to render in the default format of reStructuredText. See https://pypi.org/help/#description-content-type for more information.
```

please help ive never done this before and ive been folowing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhpI6Yhz9_4) youtube video

Comment: The upload URL seems wrong to me. I'd rather recommend this guide: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi -- Anyway the error seems to be about the "description". The value for `long_description_content_type` should be `text/x-rst`. Even though the file extension is `.txt` the content is still _restructuredtext_. -- You should run `twine check` before uploading.

Comment: ì changed `txt` to `text/x-rst` and got the same error  and befor i added it i got the same error (i just added it to test if that fixed it)

Comment: Then probably the content of the README has an issue. -- Run `twine check dist/*` -- Maybe add an empty line after the section underline, and remove the extra dash of hte underline.

Comment: You can also copy/paste and check your restructuredtext on this website: http://rst.ninjs.org/

Comment: @sinoroc i did the thin and got https://pastebin.com/LRyzNcRK

Comment: Please use https://test.pypi.org/ for experiments.

Comment: @wim how do u use that?  ive added both pypi and testpypi to the $HOME/.pypirc with the tokens and repository and all that

Comment: You have your answer: "_line 8: Error: Unexpected indentation_"

Comment: @sinoroc in what file?   setup.py   cause whn i tested it on the webside someone menstioned it said something about indentation on line 9 so i fixed that and still didnt work

Comment: No, not in `setup.py`. This is all explained clearly in the error message. Line 8 of the content of `long_description`. Which in your case is the concatenation `README.txt` and `CHANGELOG.txt`.

Comment: @sinoroc in those files there is no indentations and a total of 7 lines (1 in readme and 6 in changelog)

Comment: Plus the 2 newlines that are  added in between. That's at least 9 lines. Right?

Answer (score 1):

The content type `txt` is not a valid content type, you should use `text/plain` instead for plaintext:

```py
long_description_content_type='text/plain',
```

Furthermore, it looks like you're using an old version of `setuptools` from before `long_description_content_type` existed, you should upgrade to the latest version:

```
$ python3 -m pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: I installed setuptools today bul ill try

Comment: Can you confirm that you're removing the old distribution (in `dist`) and rebuilding with `setup.py` every time? Can you upload the resulting `.tar.gz` file online somewhere so we can take a look at it?

Comment: i do the command every tome after i eddit something but i can try to delete it and do the command   Command btw: `python3 setup.py sdist`